# How to get allocation pressure in Java Mission Control that ships with Java 10?

Tags: java, jmc

In the version of Java Mission Control that ships with Java 8, there is an "Allocation" tab that indicates the amount of pressure each allocation type places on the garbage collector.

[image: screenshop from Java 8]

It looks like Oracle totally revamped the user interface because I can't find this information under the "Memory" or "TLAB Allocations" tabs in Java 10.

Where can one find this information?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed 'pressure' metric was removed in Java Mission Control 6 included in Java 10.
Find here the related ticket: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JMC-5923 which seems to have been fixed in JMC 7.1.0.

Comment: By the way, it seems JMC 7 is not publicy released yet... https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/ea-jsp-142245.html

Comment: JMC-5293 does not look fixed BTW, jira ticket is in open state.

Comment: Just a note that JMC-5293 comes from https://community.oracle.com/message/14756066, might be some slightly useful workarounds mentioned there

Comment: Correct, it seems that for the time being they have just added it to the version 7.1.0 scope.